# Problem with directory in Heroku with Flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm having a problem with my project on Heroku, when I download a video from Youtube on localhost I used a code that takes the user's name and puts it in the Donwload directory, but in Heroku it doesn't put it there, I suspect it is with some problem when it comes to finding the director's place

```html
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def getvalue():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['url']
        try:
            url = name
            youtube = pytube.YouTube(url)
            video = youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            audio = youtube.streams.get_audio_only()
            video_path = r'C:/Users/' + getpass.getuser() + '/Downloads/Youtube_Download'
            audio_path = r'C:/Users/' + getpass.getuser() + '/Downloads/Youtube_Download/Audio'
            if not os.path.exists(video_path):
                os.makedirs(video_path)
                os.makedirs(audio_path)

            video.download(video_path)
            audio.download(audio_path)

            return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Heroku's servers most likely runs on linux, and the filesystem does not have a 'Downloads' folder. Try using a special folder you create with your app.

Comment: This is an answer to you're question, but as you are facing problems with Heroku directories I just wanted to mention that in Heroku files are all case sensetive, so avoid capital letters in file names, I faced this issue a lot where it would run on my pc but not able to make it work on heroku because the file's name had a capital letter in it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no `C:/Users/' in the Heroku Dyno, since is a Linux environment.

The folder structure there will match your project folder structure.

But I don't actually recommend store any user data inside the Heroku Dyno since will be erased every time you restart the app (e.g. when deploying a new version)
You can use a Storage Bucket like Amazon S3 for this instead.